# Finding Trending searches for an express app

Tags: node.js, postgresql, algorithm, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to implement a feature that displays the trending searches and i dont know how to go about this.I thought of creating a sql table that stores all the search words and increasing the count whenever someone searches for it.But I dont thinkl it'll be effective.So please help me out with a new method.Im using postgresSql,node js and express js in the backend.Any help would be appreciated

Comment: For a small site ie sub 10-20k daily users postgresSql would be find. Beyond that this is what tools like Elasitcsearch are made for.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. If possible can you tell me how the table structure should look like?

Comment: Sorry, no. You are going to need to do research. This is not an easy task. Example `https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/using-postgresql-to-create-an-efficient-search-engine_595344` also do search for gin index. Also, here is some code dealing with search `https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/788`

Comment: I keep mentally going back to elasticsearch. I don't know what your background is but if you have a decent ops/devops background and can setup a complex application like elasticsearch then you could very quickly have a very fast search engine. If you have a background in Docker/containers then you can spin up elasticsearch very quickly.

Comment: I will definitely try that.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, after all the search logs are collected, the most searched queries are sequentially extracted and used. 
This is a method of analyzing logs, extracting keywords and using them as popular search terms.

That is, a separate server synchronizes popular search terms based on logs and stores them in the DB. It was built and used separately from the main framework.

after this, There are a lot of advanced work. 
for examples,

1. preventing malicious manipulation through duplicate search
2. weighting by relevance of the search words
3. ...